# Inspecting dependencies of static libs / executables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, static

I have a rather large project with a whole bunch of linked dependencies. The problem is that there's a dependency getting linked to which was compiled with VS 2005 and links with the vc80 debug crt, while I've migrated to VS 2008. The problem is that this also means that I must have the vc80 debug crt installed, something which I'd rather avoid since I have no use of having VS 2005 installed anymore. I'd love to be able to track down the culprit and avoid recompiling the entire project and all dependencies from scratch, so, is there perhaps a convinient way to find out which dependency is linking to the vc80 debug crt?

Answer (score 9):

It seems dumpbin does the trick with the -directives switch, very handy. It displays various helpful information about the lib file, amongst other things all linked dependencies and their versions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will work for you, but give [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) a look.

Comment: Why do you post the exact same answer like chills42 did 9 minutes before?

Comment: @milan1612: Um... their answers weren't visible when I posted.